# visual studio's font is squished vertically

Tags: visual-studio, consolas

I'm apparently extremely picky/pedantic. But something happened and now my font is being squished by 1-3 pixels and it is driving me NUTS!

I know that there is a power productivity tool that will vertically shrink "unimportant lines" (i.e. lines that just have a brace on them, or that are empty). This is not the same problem.

Visual Studio Code seems to be unaffected. I'm using the default font - Consolas, size 13.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it - It was the display scaling. My laptop is hooked up to a 43" 4k monitor. I had it changed it a few days ago from 150% to 125%. When I changed the scaling back to 100% or 150% the problem fixed itself (and changed the font size up or down, respectively).

It was clear that the overall line didn't change in height, but when it was set to 125%, the spacing between the lines grew in proportion to the glyphs on the line. I have a feeling that if I was using 125% scaling with a size 12 or size 16 font, it would have been divisible by 4. that is just a guess though. I think there was just a rounding issue with 125% and 13pt font and it gave extra space above the glyphs instead of to the glyph itself.

I've taken screenshots but they don't really do it justice because things get re-scaled and it is hard to appreciate.